# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Map<Object,List<ActorContents>>> to Map<Actor ,Map<String,List<ActorContents>>>

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to create nested map from a list. With the below snippet I get compile time error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from
>   `Map<Object,Map<Object,List<ActorContents>>>` to   `Map<Actor,Map<String,List<ActorContents>>>`

```
 Map<Actor, List<String>> actorTypeOfContents = typeofContentforActor(genres, genreId);

            Map<Actor, Map<String, List<ActorContents>>> imageMap1=                 
                actorContents.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getActor(), Collectors.groupingBy( p -> Utility.find(actorTypeOfContents.get(p.getActor()), i -> StringUtils.contains(p.getName(), "_" + i + "_"))
                                )));
```

Utility method used is as below

```
public static <T> T find(List<T> items, Predicate<T> matchFunction) {
        for (T possibleMatch : items) {
            if (matchFunction.test(possibleMatch)) {
                return possibleMatch;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I change the code as below There is no error and code executes.

```
List<String> actorNames =actorTypeOfContents.get(Actor.Genre1);

Map<Actor, Map<String, List<ActorContents>>> imageMap1=                 
                actorContents.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getActor(), Collectors.groupingBy( p -> Utility.find(actorNames, i -> StringUtils.contains(p.getName(), "_" + i + "_"))
                                )));
```

Could you help to figure out what is wrong with the snippet

```
Map<Actor, Map<String, List<ActorContents>>> imageMap1=                 
                actorContents.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getActor(), Collectors.groupingBy( p -> Utility.find(actorTypeOfContents.get(p.getActor()), i -> StringUtils.contains(p.getName(), "_" + i + "_"))
                                )));
```

Your assistance is highly appreciated

Comment: Show the stacktrace. We can't read your mind.

Comment: This is a compile time error as mentioned in the question. Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Map<Object,List<ActorContents>>> to Map<Actor ,Map<String,List<ActorContents>>>.

Comment: This presumably depends on the thing which is different between the two snippets, i.e. `actorTypeOfContents.get(p.getActor())`, so we need to know what that does.

Comment: While compiler (and which version) are you using? Are you using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider the inner map `Map<Object,List<ActorContents>>` only, since the outer has the same issue. Consider this:

```
Map<Object,List<ActorContents>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, Arrays.asList(new ActorContents()));
map.put("one", Arrays.asList(new ActorContents()));
```

Now, you've a map with 2 keys that are different data types. You're asking the compiler to convert it into a map with a specific type for the key (`Actor`). The compiler doesn't know how to convert an integer or a string to an `Actor`.

I deliberately didn't reference your code because after reading my explanation, you should be able to figure out the problem yourself. It'll also do you good to read the [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) tutorial.

Comment: I’ve read your explanation and I don’t know how it can help the OP solving the problem. You just wrote some commonplace about generics.